# extract certain columns in python with logic

Tags: python

I am trying to extract certain columns from my data.

Below is the list of columns that I want to extract:
GA01020, GA01030, GA01040, GA01050, GA01060, GA01070, GA01080, GA01090, GA01100

I have write a code which makes me to get column until GA01090 but I can't find a way that I can get GA01100 as well.
Can you please help me to find a way to get all the 9 columns?

```
engineCount = 8
engineData = {}
for no in range(engineCount):
    engineNo = str(no+1)
cols = ['GA010' + str(i) + str(engineNo) for i in range(20, engineCount*10+11,10)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
engineCount = 8
cols = ['GA0' + str(i+1000) + str(engineCount) for i in range(20,engineCount*10+21,10)]
```

Comment: Yes, That's exactly what I want it. Thanks!

Comment: how can I can a desire column if the names of columns are GA02220,GA02230,GA02240,GA02250,GA02260,GA02270,GA02280,GA02290,GA02291?

Comment: You can do: `cols = ['GA022' + str(i) for i in range(20,engineCount*10+11,10)] + ['GA02291']` because the last one is an outlier.

Comment: Hi, Few of my data set has GA02291 and others doesn't so I want to find a way to include GA02291 with logic, not like +['GA02291']. Is there possible way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Ok now that I understand your question better try this:

```
#Assuming that you have your data sets in dataframes in a list or dict

data_sets = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
cols =['GA01020', 'GA01030', 'GA01040', 'GA01050', 'GA01060', 'GA01070', 'GA01080', 'GA01090', 'GA01100']
new_set=[]

for data in data_sets:
    new_set.append(data.loc[:, data.columns.isin(cols)])
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have 4 different data set and two of data sets have GA01100 but others doesn't have it so I want to find a way to include GA01100 in cols, not in separate line.